# Search for patterns/images inside other images using neural networks

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, neural-network, image-recognition, backpropagation

I am new to neural networks and do get the gist about how they work. I intend to create a neural network that recognize basic objects in a 3d scene and their positions in the image.

From what i read so far, the typical approach is to create a neural network with the input number of neurons of image_width * image_height * 3 (for each color) and then back propagate (a basic example for image recognition [can be found here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19323/Image-Recognition-with-Neural-Networks). I also read about smarter approaches. The problem is, that because i'm still learning, i intend to keep a basic approach to get the info synched in (which may or may not be do-able with beginner status).

How can i do so in a straight-forward method? The real project is to move around a scene and detect certain basic (or not in the future) objects like balls.

This is pure academic so the actual scope of the task is to learn so not-perfect-solutions are also taken into account.

[image: ball in view]

---

> What i would like would be to detect the ball in the image and
>   actually have the ball position

---

Answer (score 3):

Here is a good URL for you, you could read about solving similar task (locating facial key points in Images using DNN): http://danielnouri.org/notes/2014/12/17/using-convolutional-neural-nets-to-detect-facial-keypoints-tutorial/

Long story short:
1) This is a regression task. You need to create and train ANN which will output x,y coordinates of the object you are interested in
2) You need to use convolutional neural networks to achieve it - they dramatically increase effectiveness of work with images

Answer (score 1):

Usually, is not necessary to use the colors of the object for its detection and this just adds extra complexity. That’s why usually grayscale image is used for detection/classification of objects basically.

You can use [deep reinforcement learning](http://www.drlearner.org/doc/DRL.pdf) approach for training of artificial neuron networks (ANN) with a combination of conventional and fully connected 
ANN’s to detect and object.

As an alternative, I can suggest you using of scan an image with rectangle and then you will have not only detection, but also position of the rectangle.

In addition, you can use some other methods for the training of the ANN like a [method](http://3dboom.com.ua/news.php?news_id=33), which I’m using currently for task of fabric defect detection and also it was tested by the face recognition task

In fact, a combination of methods gives better result than using a single approach.

In my case with the task of fabric error detection by using both of the mentioned above (ANN clusters and scanning window with overlapping) for the particular case it gives me 0.1024% probability of false detection of the error and 15% for not detection of error for entire image.

And with the using of a combination with [Gaussian filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_filter), in the addition, we reached less than 0.0324% probability of false detection and less than 5% for not detection as well as performance was increased more than 10 times.

Here is a [link](http://united.softserveinc.com/blogs/automation-defects-detection-2015/) to the article with detailed description of approaches which I'm using for fabric errors detection